# join() doesn't block other threads (except main)?

Tags: java, multithreading

Our teacher gave us the following code:

```
public static void main(String[]args) {
Thread a = new Thread(new T(2));
Thread b = new Thread(new T(5));

a.start();
b.start();

try {
a.join(); //Thread a now runs completely to the end, before the main-method gets back to a "runnable" state

    b.join(); //Thread b runs to death before the main methods u
    } catch (InterruptedException ie) {}

    System.out.println("done");  //Result: Random Thread a and b outputs
                                 //and in the end "done" from main
    }

public class T extends Thread {
private int nr;
public T(int nr) {
this.nr = nr;
}

public void run() {
for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
System.out.println("Hello " + nr + " " + i);
}
}
```

Thread a and b are the same and both write (in a for-loop) 10 prints to the console.
Thread a and b were finished, before the main method stopped and all results were random except the main method.

My question was, if it shouldn't also block the other threads(not just main), if you call `join()` on one thread. He said, that join() just freezes the main method. But for what reason should this be good? He also said, that this is totally random and managed by the scheduler, which doesn't make sense for this part in my opinion (the scheduler commands the thread-states, this is clear, but not after calling join(), at least not for the java application. Or am I false?). My point would be, that Thread a and b ran completely to the end, before the main-thread even called the join method. Javadoc tells me the same, if I understand it correct.

I hope someone of you can give me an answer. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The call to `join()` on an instance of `Thread` will not complete until the thread corresponding to that instance dies.

Corrollary 1: if that thread is already dead, `join()` returns immediately.

Corrollary 2: no threads except the current are affected by this call.

> He also said, that this is totally random and managed by the scheduler

You probably didn't catch exactly what the teacher said here. Thread scheduling, which means making decisions when a thread will be given some CPU time to run, and how much of it, is done by the thread scheduler. It is definitely not "totally random" and for most practical considerations, all threads run all the time. Again, this has little to do with the behavior of the `join` method.

Comment: just my 2 cents. Totally random in this context means that programmer has no clue to predict or manage when threads will run or suspend.

Comment: @holap I object to the conflation of "unspecified" with "totally random" because the latter is actually a much *stronger* statement and allows the derivation of false conclusions.

Comment: I understood, what the teacher wanted to tell me. But is it really like this? Does join() really just bring the thread to the state "wait" and the rest is the task of the scheduler? How can a thread "wait" for another thread, if he hasn't the "power" to really wait for it (because java cannot manage it by itself).
Actually, this method sounds 100% useless to me, if I didn't get it false.
Anyway, thanks for your answer! :) I think it is not totally clear, what I wanted to ask with my start-post. Sorry for my english.

Comment: It has the power to wait for it, and that's what it does. I'm not sure what you mean by "java cannot manage it by itself". Java doesn't directly manage the bytes written to a block device, yet that doesn't stop you from trusting it to open and write a file.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, join() blocks all other threads until the thread, where join() has been called, dies. But in my example, there is a random-thread output and "done" will be printed in the end. If calling join() would work, there would be the complete output of thread a, then the complete output of thread b and in the end the output of main.
I hope you understand me, otherwise I will later fix my question and showing you, what the output looks like. :)

Comment: You do not understand correctly. In fact, I am struggling hard to see how you could possibly have got that message from my answer, which goes out of its way to state the exact opposite.

Answer (score 0):

The point of `join` is not to give a single thread priority over all others. Rather, it's to express that one thread needs to wait for another thread to complete before that (first) thread can go on. It's not always the main thread calling `join`. It's a single constraint being placed on the scheduler: "Don't do A until you've done B". Of course, by using multiple `join`s, you can accomplish more complex dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the point your teacher was trying to make is that **you cannot assume** anything other than the contract of `join`. I.e. the main thread will not continue until `a` has run to completion.

It is quite possible for `a.join()` to allow `b` to continue but it is also possible for it to completely block `b` until `a` is complete.

If you tested this code on a single-core machine it is actually quite likely that `a.join()` will exclude `b` but on a multi-core machine it may not.